# Embedded Jetty resourceBase classpath URL

Tags: spring, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm embedding Jetty in a Spring based application. I configure my Jetty server in a Spring context file. The specific part of the configuration I'm having trouble with is this:

```
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <property name="contextPath" value="/" />
   <property name="resourceBase" value="????????" />
   <property name="parentLoaderPriority" value="true" />
</bean>
```

If you see above, where I've put the ????????, I ideally want the resourceBase to reference a folder on my classpath. I'm deploying my application in a single executable JAR file and have a folder `config/web/WEB-INF` on my classpath.

Jetty seems to be able to handle URLs defined in the resourceBase (e.g. `jar:file:/myapp.jar!/config/web`) but it doesn't seem to support classpath URLs. I get an IllegalArgumentException if I define something like `classpath:config/web`.

This is a real pain for me. Does anyone know of anyway to achieve this functionality?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get your resource as a Spring's `Resource` and call `getURI().toString()` on it, something like this:

```
public class ResourceUriFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<String> {

    private Resource resource;

    public ResourceUriFactoryBean(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    protected String createInstance() throws Exception {
        return resource.getURI().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends String> getObjectType() {
        return String.class;
    }    
}
```

-

```
<property name="resourceBase">
    <bean class = "com.metatemplating.sample.test.ResourceUriFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg value = "classpath:config/web" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

-

Or more elegant approach with Spring 3.0's expression language:

```
<property name="resourceBase" 
    value = "#{new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource('config/web').getURI().toString()}" />
```

Comment: Nice one. If you're not using Spring, just use SomeClass.class.getResource("/config/web").toURI().toString()